# $\forall\,T>0:\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx\le K<\infty$, $K$ independent of $T$, $f$ uniformly continuous, non-negative $\implies$ $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Below is my first try at writing what I have so far. I would appreciate your feedback.

---

Assume towards a contradiction that the claim is wrong. Thus, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ for which there exists an increasing sequence, $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, that satisfies $f(x_n) > \epsilon$ for all $n$. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $y$ that satisfies $|x - y| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Since $f$ is non-negative, for all $n$, for all $x \in [x_n-\delta, x_n+\delta]$, it holds that $f(x) > \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore, for all $n$, we have $\int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta} f(x) \,dx > \left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) \left(2\delta\right) = \epsilon \delta$, which does not depend on $n$. Concluding that $\int_0^T f(x)\,dx=\infty$ as $T \to \infty$. In particular, there must exist $T>0$ such that $\int_0^Tf(x)\,dx > K$, in a contradiction. QED.

Comment: The negation of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ is not $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \ne 0$ because the limit might not exist.

Comment: Also the statement seems to be wrong, $f(x) = 1$ is uniformly continuous, with $\int_0^T f(x) dx  = T < \infty$ for all $T > 0$.

Comment: What you *perhaps* mean is that $\int_0^T f(x) dx \le K < \infty$ for some constant $K$, independent of $T$.

Comment: Please see the fixed statement.

Comment: Aside: I learned recently, by way of https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1611, that this result is apparently known as Barbălat's lemma.

Comment: You may need to clarify the word "$f$ is uniformly continuous". Do you mean "$f$ is uniformly continuous over $[0,\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall your proof is mostly correct, except for a few minor points. When you say there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon/2\delta$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$, this is incorrect. Given any $\epsilon'>0$, you are allowed to conclude there is some $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon'$ provided $|x-y|<\delta$, but $\epsilon'$ cannot depend on $\delta$, since $\delta$ comes only after picking $\epsilon'$.

However, this is mostly an inessential point since if you simply replace $\epsilon/2\delta$ with something like $\epsilon/10$, then you conclude instead that $\int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta}f \ge c\epsilon\delta$, for some appropriate choice of constant $c$, which is a bound that is independent of $n$.

One other important point is that, while I agree you outlined the essential step to showing that you will obtain a contradiction, you need to properly finish the argument. In particular, to draw the contradiction, it will be important to make explicit use of the fact that the points $x_n$ tend to infinity, which you didn't yet use. Remember the aim is to show that for some $T>0$, $\int_0^T f > K$, contradicting the hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: Please see the edited post.

Comment: @keyboardAnt: You fixed the part where you invoke uniform continuity, but you need to use the assumption the points $x_n\to\infty$. How does that get used? It wouldn't work if the points $x_n$ converged.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous over $[0,\infty)$. Prove
by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $f(x)\not\rightarrow0$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$. That is, there exists $a>0$ such that for
any $X>0$, there exists $x\geq X$ such that $f(x)=|f(x)-0|\geq a$.
From which we can choose a sequence $(x_{n})$ of non-negative real
numbers by recursion such that $1\leq x_{1}<x_{2}<\ldots$, $x_{n}-x_{n-1}>1$,
and $f(x_{n})\geq a$ for all $n$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such
that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{1}{2}a$ whenever $|x-y|\leq\delta$. Let
$\delta_{1}=\min(\delta,\frac{1}{2})$. Note that $x_{n-1}+\delta_{1}<x_{n}-\delta_{1}$
for all $n$, so $\{[x_{n}-\delta_{1},x_{n}+\delta_{1}]$ $\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is a family of pairwisely disjoint intervals. Moreover, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$
and $x\in[x_{n}-\delta_{1},x_{n}+\delta_{1}]$, since $|x-x_{n}|\leq\delta$,
we have that $|f(x)-f(x_{n})|<\frac{a}{2}\Rightarrow f(x)\geq f(x_{n})-\frac{a}{2}>\frac{a}{2}$.
Therefore, $\int_{x_{n}-\delta_{1}}^{x_{n}+\delta_{1}}f(x)dx\geq\frac{a}{2}\cdot2\delta_{1}=a\delta_{1}$.

By Archimedean principle, we can choose $n$ such that $a\delta_{1}n>K$.
Now, since the intervals are non-overlapping and $f(x)\geq 0$, we have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{0}^{x_{n}+\delta_{1}}f(x)dx\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{x_{k}-\delta_{1}}^{x_{k}+\delta_{1}}f(x)dx\\
 & \geq & \sum_{k=1}^{n}a\delta_{1}\\
 & = & a\delta_{1}n\\
 & > & K,
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction.